# Workbooks.Open is not using the provided Password, but instead requesting password from user

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening a whole bunch of workbooks that all have the same password in order to check their sheets.

The program starts with a dummy password that will fail, and when it does a userform (named `PasswordUserform`) is shown in order to capture the password for all of the files. Subsequently, each workbook is opened via that password. As such, it should A) never fail, and B) never use the default password entry userform.

```
Private Function CheckFiles(ByRef WkbApp As Excel.Application, _
            WkbFolder As String, _
            FoundFile As String, _
            NeededSheets As Scripting.Dictionary, _
            ByRef Pass As String) As Boolean

    Dim Wkb As Workbook

    WkbApp.Visible = False

    ' Attempts to open the workbook. If it fails, then attempts to get a
    '  better password from the user. This password is saved for further
    '  attempts, but only during runtime.
    On Error Resume Next
        Set Wkb = WkbApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WkbFolder & FoundFile, _
                    Password:=Pass)

        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            PasswordUserform.FileNameLabel.Caption = "'" & _
                    Left(FoundFile, 20) & "...'"
            PasswordUserform.Show

            Pass = PasswordUserform.PasswordBox.Text
            Unload PasswordUserform

            Set Wkb = WkbApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WkbFolder & FoundFile, _
                        Password:=Pass)
        End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Do Stuff within workbook, Setting function to True or False depending on contents
End Function
```

The function is called within a simple Do While loop:

```
    Do While Len(FoundFile) > 0
        FoundDate = FileDateTime(WkbFolder & FoundFile)
        If FoundDate > LatestDate And CheckFiles(WkbApp, WkbFolder, _
                    FoundFile, NeededSheets, Pass) Then
            LatestDate = FoundDate
            LatestFile = FoundFile
            LatestPass = Pass
        End If

        FoundFile = Dir
    Loop
```

When stepping through, the first `Set Wkb` may or may not display the default password userform. If that pops up and is cancelled, the custom `PasswordUserform` displays. On proper entry, the second `Set Wkb` (in the IF scope) always displays the default password userform. But on the next file, the password is used properly and no userform is displayed. Finally, the occasional file will create the default password userform (on inputting the password that should have been provided, it opens fine, as all files in the folder use the same password).

I've tried setting the `WriteResPassword` as well, with no difference. Additionally, `DisplayAlerts=False` does not prevent the problem.

Comment: It would be better to restrict the scope of your `On Error Resume Next` to only the line which tries to open the workbook - then check `If Wkb Is Nothing` to find out if there was a problem.  As it stands your current code could be ignoring a bunch of other kinds of problems.

Comment: Why not just ask the user up front for the password, if the files are always going to be protected?

Comment: @TimWilliams That is the only UI that appears, so it doesn't matter where in the code it is placed. However, if they decide to start using a different password, or to use multiple passwords, then having this in the loop will be no worse (but possibly still better) than relying on each workbook to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was `WkbApp.Visible = False`. By setting the Application invisible, when the macro inevitably crashed during future testing, it would not fail gracefully, and therefore the application and its workbooks would still exist, but be unviewable by the user.

When the macro is run again, it sees that the file is locked for editing, but instead of displaying the locked for editing alert, it just asked for the password again (not sure why this is what it does).

Changing the Application to:

```
Set ResultApp = New Excel.Application
ResultApp.WindowState = xlMinimized
ResultApp.Visible = True
```

Allows the user to close the window when things go horribly wrong.

Additionally, using the `ReadOnly` parameter allows the program to open a copy regardless of if it is open.

```
Set Wkb = WkbApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WkbFolder & FoundFile, _
            Password:=Pass, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Since I am saving to a new file anyway, this works for me, but may not if someone wishes to edit&save the file they open.

I would be happy to learn of any way to capture a hard crash and gracefully close~